# xrandrを使ったUbuntuのデュアルディスプレイができません。。

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu14.04をWindowsとデュアルブートして使っています。LVDS1のデスクトップとVGA1の外部モニタでデュアルディスプレイを試みようとしていますが、うまくいきません。普段はLVDS1に映して使用しているのですが、VGAコネクタで外部ディスプレイにつなげると、LVDS1では映らなくなり、VGA1のみ映るようになってしまいます。

VGAコネクタをはずしてxrandrを実行すると以下のように結果が表示されます。

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024      59.7*+
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

一方、VGAコネクタにつなげてxrandrを実行すると、以下のようになります。

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1440 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 255mm
   1440x900       59.9 +   75.0* 
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

VGAコネクタを接続した状態でLVDS1も接続された状態で操作したいのですが、どのように設定すればよいか分かりません。
どなたかご教授頂けると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ハードウェアの制限ということはありませんでしょうか。Windows ではできるのでしょうか?

Comment: windowで起動すると問題なくデュアルディスプレイになります。
この時は何も設定しなくても自然となりました。

Answer (score 1):

--left-of/--right-of/--above/--below などのオプションでマルチディスプレイにできませんでしょうか。
`xrandr --output VGA1 --right-of LVDS1`

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
そのようなオプションで実行してみたところエラーなどはなく通るようですが、画面に変化がありませんでした。

Comment: 失礼しました。
"LVDS1 disconnected" になってしまうのですね。 
Windows では問題ないとのことですので、Linux kernel か Xorg のドライバーに問題があるのかもしれません。

症状が似ている、以下のバグ報告では解決していないようです。
  https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63172
  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1071288